# Java: Application Blocked by Security Setting

Tags: java

I have a web application that uses Java 6 update 22 and was working fine until yesterday and now all of sudden when I try to load a form from my application it says "Application Blocked by Security Setting" I can't update to the latest Java b/c it's not compatible and I can't set the Java security setting to Medium from high since it is a risk. I have multiple users experiencing this issue, any ideas? I know Windows released their updates recently and not sure if that could be a factor as I couldn't find anything, thanks.

Comment: Unless the interface to your app is an applet, this is not a Java problem. More likely is that the security settings in your browser have been changed.

Comment: When I click on the form it tries to load the Java and then the error pops-up. The URL is listed in our Local Intranet Zone and the Scripting of Java Applets is enabled in setting. I don't know what other setting would make it work, only if i lower the security to Medium then it works.

Comment: Ok, so the application we are running if we stay running @ an older version it is working now b/c I completely uninstalled and then reinstall and rebooted so I'm good, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If changing the security level to medium doesn't help you can go to the *Windows Control Panel* -> *Programs* -> *Java*. There you go to *Security* and press *Edit Site List...*, click *Add* and there you type in the location (the URL where the app is hosted) and press *OK*.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i have tried both of your suggestion but still cannot resolved the matter, got any more option mr?

Comment: Sorry, that's the two suggestions I found when I had this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the Java security level to **medium** or better whitelist your Java app. [Here is how to do it.](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)

Comment: for my case, the problen still occur

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your application is a Java applet. Is it?

Running old versions of the java plugin in your browser, unfortunately, is a big security risk. Others can insert malicious applets on web pages and gain access to the user's computer by exploiting known bugs in the old java plugin.

Perhaps you can use java webstart instead? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html and [Opening JNLP File in Java 6 JRE instead of JRE 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744841/opening-jnlp-file-in-java-6-jre-instead-of-jre-7)

You could also try signing the jarfile(s) of your applet, if you have not already done so.

Comment: When I click on the form it tries to load the Java and then the error pops-up. The URL is listed in our Local Intranet Zone and the Scripting of Java Applets is enabled in setting. I don't know what other setting would make it work, only if i lower the security to Medium then it works. How do I use the java webstart?

Comment: I've added a link to the tutorial for java webstart