# Java web start JRE auto download for non oracle java

Tags: java, java-web-start

We have tricky situation with out Java Web start project where I need restrict it running on IBM JRE. Otherwise it will not connect back to my cloud application. There are various reason we are restricting to IBM JRE, one of them is cryptographic features.

Having said that, I have tried following things.
Added following tag in my jnlp

```xml
<j2se version="1.7.0_72+"  href="http://9.182.74.244:8080/jreInstaller/download"/>
```

where /jreinstaller/download URI served by a servlet.

I have followed exactly how it was mentioned by unofficial web start project. 
http://lopica.sourceforge.net/services/index.html

With Oracle Java I am getting below behavior. Instead calling my servlet which it is prompting below popup and running whatever available.

> This application would like to use a version of Java (1.7.0_71+) that is not installed on your system. We recommend running the application with latest version of Java on your computer.

Am I missing something, how was unofficial web start services were working previously. Something changed with latest Java?

Comment: I think the [answer lies here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13759168/418556)..

Comment: did not work, its not calling my servlet when jnlp finds that the request java does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Oracle removed the JRE auto-download feature from Web Start in 2013: [openjdk bug 8006701](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8006701). Web Start now often (but not always) silently ignores the version specification.